# Torchlight - How many levels are there before beating the story?

Tags: torchlight

How many level or floors are there before beating the story?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I recall correctly the main dungeon has 35 floors. Of course, you may play an infinite number of floors even before finishing the main story, on account of treasure maps and the like.

Comment: Once you beat the last boss, the entrance to the infinite dungeon (the crypt) appears in town, along with a couple new questgivers.